# Sylius and overwriting default fixtures

Tags: sylius

I try to overwrite default fixtures. I create config\packages\sylius_fixtures.yaml with content exacly like in documentation https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.12/customization/fixtures.html#how-to-modify-the-existing-sylius-fixtures

```
sylius_fixtures:
    suites:
        default: # this key is always called whenever the sylius:fixtures:load command is called, below we are extending it with new fixtures
            fixtures:
                currency:
                    options:
                        currencies: ['PLN','HUF']
                channel:
                    options:
                        custom:
                            pl_web_store: # creating new channel
                                name: "PL Web Store"
                                code: "PL_WEB"
                                locales:
                                    - "%locale%"
                                currencies:
                                    - "PLN"
                                enabled: true
                                hostname: "localhost"
                            hun_web_store:
                                name: "Hun Web Store"
                                code: "HUN_WEB"
                                locales:
                                    - "%locale%"
                                currencies:
                                    - "HUF"
                                enabled: true
                                hostname: "localhost"
                shipping_method:
                    options:
                        custom:
                            ups_eu: # creating a new shipping_method and adding channel to it
                                code: "ups_eu"
                                name: "UPS_eu"
                                enabled: true
                                channels:
                                    - "PL_WEB"
                                    - "HUN_WEB"
                payment_method:
                    options:
                        custom:
                            cash_on_delivery_pl:
                                code: "cash_on_delivery_eu"
                                name: "Cash on delivery_eu"
                                channels:
                                    - "PL_WEB"
                            bank_transfer:
                                code: "bank_transfer_eu"
                                name: "Bank transfer_eu"
                                channels:
                                    - "PL_WEB"
                                    - "HUN_WEB"
                                enabled: true
```

When I run fixtures by "docker compose exec php bin/console sylius:fixtures:load" I got errors:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thx to Francis from Sylius community I understood how it works. I was trying to replace values of the default sylius fixtures, but by default Symfony configs are array_merge recursively, so I wasn't able to just overwrite the current configuration.

To solve my problem, I copied a whole directory with any fixtures, from vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/app/fixtures/* to my project in config/packages/dev/fixtures/* and I change suite name, from default to my own. Now, beginning of my shop_configuration.yaml looks like:

```
sylius_fixtures:
    suites:
        b2b_omnicommerce:
            listeners:
                orm_purger: ~
                images_purger: ~
                logger: ~

            fixtures:
                locale:
                    priority: 7
                    options:
                        locales:
                            - 'pl_PL'
                            - 'en_US'
                currency:
...
```

I just had to add fixtures priority to represent the same import order like in vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/app/fixtures.yml

[image]

So, for fixtures in shop_configuration.yaml I added priority 7 and for last one custom_fixtures.yaml I added priority 0.

And at the end, I need to change my docker build to run as default my new fixtures suit, so I found any "php bin/console sylius:fixtures:load" in my project and I changed it to "php bin/console sylius:fixtures:load b2b_omnicommerce"

The last step was to rebuild my project by:

```
docker compose up -d --build
```

Now I can change the default and put my own configuration. I hope this information will be useful to someone.